# Structure/Format of Gradle exceptions

Tags: gradle, build, documentation

I am currently working on a project which requires to analyze Gradle exceptions from randomly built android applications from Github.

Is there any specify documentation available which describe how Gradle exceptions look like ?.

**Update:**

To be more specific, I want to understand the following structure:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>
> Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [Gradle API documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/GradleException.html) where you can find `GradleException` which is base class of all exceptions thrown by Gradle together with all subclasses that inherit from it.

**Edit:** typical build exception looks as below and is handled by `BuildExceptionReporter` class (see source [**[link]**](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/7e5343e01c8635d4318363a850a5418aa42aac53/subprojects/internal-integ-testing/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/integtests/fixtures/executer/OutputScrapingExecutionFailure.java) where you can find details of how the exception message is constructed)

```
Error:16:12:04.890 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
16:12:04.891 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
16:12:04.891 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
16:12:04.891 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
16:12:04.891 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Task 'option' not found in root project 'Design'.
16:12:04.891 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
16:12:04.891 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
16:12:04.891 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. 
16:12:04.891 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
16:12:04.892 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
16:12:04.892 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.execution.TaskSelectionException: Task 'option' not found in root project 'Design'.
16:12:04.892 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:100)
```

Comment: This is the only exception related document I could find. But, I want something more that could explain the structure of the Gradle error message that is thrown during the build process. I will add more information to the question in regard to this.

Comment: Thanks. This helps